# Use jqueryui in index.html

Tags: jquery, html

I just finished codecademy tutorials on html, css, js and jQuery. Now I am trying to create something on my own. But I can't make even the simplest thing work. I did everything in some kind of "browser consele lab" till now. Question is, how do I use or include jQuery in my index.html so it will work when I open it in browser? After some searching I used google hosted libraries links but it still doesn't work. I have 3 files created: index.html, style.css and script.js.

Now it just loads page with that square on it, but does nothing when I click it, even tho my jQuery code should be correct.

**index.html** code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My thing</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css** code:

```
div {
height: 250px;
width: 250px;
background-color: #008800;
}
```

**script.js** code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
      $(this).effect('explode');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My thing</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.css'/>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your script page `script.js` used jQuery, so it should be included after jQuery library

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ba5ueeeXzapdw8et3t38?p=preview)

Comment: Combination of adding http: and moving my 'script.js' link after those links worked.

Comment: @ruby_ruby there is no need to add `http:` as I shown in the demo

Comment: I see it works in demo, but when I delete the http: in my file it realy doesn't explode. When I keep it there it works. Anyway thank you for helping a newbie out.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the protocol part from your script source URLs. Add either `http:` or `https:` depending on where you are getting them from.

Comment: that is fine, it will use the protocol used to load the index page

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

you miss the http: try this one and see if it works

Comment: that is fine, it will use the protocol used to load the index page